# How to generate HMAC-SHA256 in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, hash, asp.net-core, .net-core, hmac

I am using this page to generate some test HMAC-SHA256 hashes for some texts:

https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/

However, when I try to use the approach in [this MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing) in my .Net Core project, I do not get the same results. Could some one explain to me how to get identical results to those I get from the previous web page in my C# code?

Here is my code:

```
// My own GetHash method usage:
var hashed = PasswordHelper.GetHash("Test", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123"));

public static string GetHash(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
    string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
    return hashed;
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using the following approach:

```
public static String GetHash(String text, String key)
{
    // change according to your needs, an UTF8Encoding
    // could be more suitable in certain situations
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    Byte[] textBytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    Byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    Byte[] hashBytes;

    using (HMACSHA256 hash = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(textBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

you will get the same result as the site you provided:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetHash("qwerty","123456"));
// 3364ad93c083dc76d7976b875912442615cc6f7e3ce727b2316173800ca32b3a
```

Proof:

[image: Proof]

Actually, the code you are using, which is based on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing) and on `KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2`, is producing different results because it uses a much more complex parametrization and another encoding. But despite the results being different, you should **REALLY** use the approach provided by the example, and stick on the `UTF8` encoding.