# Binance API HMAC SHA256 Signature error Using C#

Tags: c#, sha256, binance

I try to connect to the `Binance Api` Using `C#` And `RestSharp` lib. Based on [documents](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#endpoint-security-type) I should try something like this:

> queryString: symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559
>
> HMAC SHA256 signature:
>
> [linux]$ echo -n
>   "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559"
>   | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac
>   "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
>   (stdin)=
>   c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71 curl
>   command:
>
> (HMAC SHA256) [linux]$ curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY:
>   vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A" -X
>   POST
>   https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71

I try many ways and many stack questions but I found solutions for other languages not c#. 
this i I done based on: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185122/calculating-hmacsha256-using-c-sharp-to-match-payment-provider-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304411/binance-api-hmac-signature)

```
public string GetAccountInfo()
    {
        long timeStamp = GetTimestamp();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/v3/account");
        request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);
        request.AddParameter("timestamp", timeStamp, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("recvWindow", RecvWindow, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("signature", GetSignature(request.Parameters), ParameterType.QueryString);
        return Client.Get(request).Content;
    }
private long GetTimestamp()
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    }

    private string GetSignature(List<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        var signature = "";
        if(parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                if(item.Name != "X-MBX-APIKEY")
                    signature += $"{item.Name}={item.Value}&";
            }
            signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 2);
        }
        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ApiSecret);
        byte[] valueBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(signature);
        return HashEncode(HashHMAC(keyBytes, valueBytes));
    }

    private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
    {
        var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
        return hash.ComputeHash(message);
    }

    private static string HashEncode(byte[] hash)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```

but I got this error: Signature for this request is not valid. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Usually failures like this require a different padding mode.  The default Net library padding is different from the default in JSON.  Also a lot of issues have been occurring with encryption in Net 4.7.  When people have been upgrading from older Net the code stopped working.  I think the default encryption modes have changed in Net to be compatible with latest encryption modes.

Comment: I don't know why exactly but I try another way and got a correct answer. see my answer @jdweng

Comment: This Answer resolve my problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686794)

Answer (score 8):

Below is the working example of signature generation:

```
    public static string CreateSignature(string queryString, string secret)
    {

        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
        byte[] queryStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
        HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

        byte[] bytes = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(queryStringBytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```

`queryString` is your string of parameters passed in query, e.g. `timestamp=1586620030079` 
`secret` is your api secret.

Important thing to note is that request fails with `Bad Request` response when you go in debug step by step because timestamp gets outside of recv window.

You could also find this SDK very useful at least as working code example: https://github.com/nathan-alexander/csharp-binance-api

Comment: Just used this in my own api. Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Binance has acknowlegded the problems us developers have with signatures, as a matter of fact they have added a signature utility to their repo [here](https://github.com/binance/binance-signature-examples).
Check out the code and adjust it to your needs, if you run the compiled C# console program like this:

```
BinanceDotNet.exe signature
```

Or like this:

```
dotnet run signature
```

You'll get a sample signature.

Best of luck