# Binance API - "Signature for this request is not valid"

Tags: c#, rest, binance

Im trying to access my binance account via the REST API and RestSharp. This is my code:

```
public void getaccountdata()
{      


        string apikey = "myapikey";
        string secret = "mysecret";  
       
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.binance.com");

        request = new RestRequest("/api/v3/time", Method.GET);

        response = client.Get(request);

        ttime testtime = new ttime();
        testtime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ttime>response.Content.ToString());

        string timestamp = testtime.serverTime;

        request = new RestRequest("/api/v3/account", Method.GET);

        request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apikey);

        request.AddQueryParameter("recvWindow", "5000");
        request.AddQueryParameter("timestamp", timestamp);

        request.AddQueryParameter("signature", CreateSignature(request.Parameters, secret));

        response = client.Get(request);
 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

}

public static string CreateSignature(List<Parameter> parameters, string secret)
{
        var signature = "";
        if (parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                if (item.Name != "X-MBX-APIKEY")
                    signature += $"{item.Name}={item.Value}&";
            }
            signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 2);
        }


        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
        byte[] queryStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
        HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

        byte[] bytes = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(queryStringBytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
  }

public class ttime
  {
        public string serverTime { get; set; }
  }
```

Basically I'm just trying to replicate the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159559/6136178). However I always get the "Signature for this request is not valid" response.

The response URI looks correct (timestamp and signature at the end according to the FAQ [here](https://dev.binance.vision/t/faq-signature-for-this-request-is-not-valid/176))

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? thx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the error was this line:

```
signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 2);
```

This removed the last character of the timestamp, so it should be:

```
signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 1);
```

So in case someone needs a simple and working example of the Binance API in C#, here the full working code again:

```
public void getaccountdata()
{        

        string apikey = "myapikey";
        string secret = "mysecret";  
       
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.binance.com");

        request = new RestRequest("/api/v3/time", Method.GET);

        response = client.Get(request);

        ttime testtime = new ttime();
        testtime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ttime>response.Content.ToString());

        string timestamp = testtime.serverTime;

        request = new RestRequest("/api/v3/account", Method.GET);

        request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apikey);

        request.AddQueryParameter("recvWindow", "5000");
        request.AddQueryParameter("timestamp", timestamp);

        request.AddQueryParameter("signature", CreateSignature(request.Parameters, secret));

        response = client.Get(request);
 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

}

public static string CreateSignature(List<Parameter> parameters, string secret)
{
        var signature = "";
        if (parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                if (item.Name != "X-MBX-APIKEY")
                    signature += $"{item.Name}={item.Value}&";
            }
            signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 1);
        }


        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
        byte[] queryStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
        HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

        byte[] bytes = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(queryStringBytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
  }

public class ttime
  {
        public string serverTime { get; set; }
  }
```